# ThreeJS draggable CSS3DObject

Tags: three.js

Been using THREE JS CSS3DRenderer to render a panorama view based in this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_panorama).

I have added another CSS3DObject image which represents a GPS marker with the following code below:

```
var marker = document.createElement( 'img' );
    marker.classList.add('gps_marker');
    marker.src = 'gps_marker.jpg';
    marker.width = 5;  
    marker.style.border = 'solid 1px red';  

var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( marker );
    object.position.set( 0, 0, 30 );
    scene.add( object );
```

Now I'd like to make the gps markers draggable around the scene around the scene. Dragcontrols doesn't seem to work with CSS3DObject. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: `DragControls` does not work with `CSS3DObjects`. I think I would switch to WebGL instead and use `WebGLRenderer`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "textured" point cloud (THREE.Points) object with shader material. Use uniform to pass texture to fragment shader. Not sure that dragcontrols will work with it (will move all points at ones if so). But this is IMHO the best way to draw icons. Example:

```
let uniforms = {    
    iconSize: {
        value: self.iconSize
    },  
    color: {
        value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff)
    },
    texture: {
        value: self.textureLoader.load(url, texture => {
            texture.flipY = false;
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
        })
    }
};              

let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('point-cloud-vertex-shader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('point-cloud-fragment-shader').textContent,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide, 
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.7,   
    depthTest: false,
    clipping: true,
    clippingPlanes: self.clippingPlanes,                    
});

//... create THREE.Points object with this material
```

shaders:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="point-cloud-vertex-shader">   

    uniform vec3 color;

    uniform float iconSize;

    uniform sampler2D texture;       

    void main() {

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );       

    gl_PointSize = iconSize;       

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

    }

</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="point-cloud-fragment-shader">   

    uniform vec3 color;

    uniform float iconSize;

    uniform sampler2D texture;

    void main() {   

    gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );

    }

</script>
```